# How to link to anchors with punctuations?

Tags: markdown

If I have a heading with punctuations:

```
## 1.1 Some section?
```

How do I write an anchor link to that section?

Comment: What Markdown processor are you using? The original one doesn't generate header links and others may use different rules from each other. Whatever you're using, you should be able to mouse over the rendered result and find the right link to use.

Comment: Edit: I see what you mean now. I looked at some rendered markdown page on Github and the link appears on the left when I hover over the heading.

Comment: Okay, now mouse over that link to see what it points to.

Comment: Got it. The anchor removes all punctuations so it's just `#11-some-section`.